# Sum a specific column of data in a 2d array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum

How can I sum this array:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [DEB_Sum] => 1
    [0] => 1
    [DEB_MovementDate] => 2014-06-13
    [1] => 2014-06-13
    [INV_Name] => Chèque bancaire
    [2] => Chèque bancaire
  )
  [1] => Array (
    [DEB_Sum] => 0.18
    [0] => 0.18
    [DEB_MovementDate] => 2014-06-15
    [1] => 2014-06-15
    [INV_Name] => Argent comptant
    [2] => Argent comptant
  )
)
```

I would like to get something like this:

```
// Sum of [DEB_Sum]
$sum = 1.18;
```

PS: how can I remove [0], [1] and [2] ?

Comment: `foreach` --- just 2 lines of code

Comment: Or maybe: `$sum = array_sum(array_map($array, function ($sub) { return $sub['DEB_sum']; }));`

Comment: is this from a database query? if so sum in the query will be faster/cleaner

Comment: for the second question try using [unset](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.unset.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($items as $item)
{
    $total += $item['DEB_Sum'];
}
```

...where `$items` is your original array.

Answer (score 0):

It clearly indicates that its the output of a database query. And you have used `$result_type = MYSQLI_BOTH` on [`*_fetch_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) function call.

If you really want to get the sum Just fetch the sum in sql.

```
SELECT sum(`DEB_Sum`) FROM ...
```